# Setup a forward proxy in apache inside a virtual server

Tags: apache, configuration, proxy

I would like to setup a forward proxy on my server but only within a specific virtual-host. For example: proxy.myserver.com
I would like all my other domain (myserver2.com) and subdomains (www.myserver.com) to remain as-is, with no proxy capabilities.

What made sense to me was to to do this:

ServerName proxy.myserver.com
ProxyRequests On

But this doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "forward proxy"?

Answer (score 0):

I use this config to forward all subdomain.domain.tld requests to my tomcat server on port:8080 (to my application called path)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName subdomain.domain.tld
ProxyPass       /path/ http://localhost:8080/path/
ProxyPassReverse  /path/ http://localhost:8080/path/
</VirtualHost>
```